# Inputs in Panelbar not receiving input in kendo-ui-angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to put a simple input inside a custom template inside of panelbar item
and as you can verify on plunker the input control just does not receive the input event.

Just see the "projects" tab.

```
            <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="'Projects'">
              <template kendoPanelBarContent>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ ticket.Name }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 150px;">
                                    <input type="number" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                     </template>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
```

[Plunker available here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FLTILsXQfJhpca8Ky76w?p=preview)

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean? Focus event?

Comment: I am just not able to type something inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the described behavior is a bug in the PanelBar. I took the time to log it in the Kendo UI for Angular issues tracker:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/283

You can follow the state of the issue in Github.

Comment: Thanks George, will follow the issue on github!

Comment: issue closed without solution, so how i can fix it?